# Python -- Is there a shorthand way to say "if (some condition), set var = [...], otherwise, set var = [something else]"?

Tags: python

Is there a shorthand way to do something like this (preferably all in one line)?

```
if something:
    var = "thing"
else:
    var = "other thing"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
 a = 3 if True else 4
```

Sets a to 3 if first condition met (here True) else to 4

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!